# What can one do when captcha doesn't work?

Tags: support, captcha

What can one do when captcha doesn't work under internet censorship?

[image]

Comment: Not enough details. If this happens with any captcha, go to [su], they already have questions like this that have answers.

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst There's no CAPTCHA box to check.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details.

Comment: Well, just don't do the action that triggered the captcha, e.g. it happens if you focus the answer editor, then copy and paste answer then submit in few seconds. Instead you can still copy and paste, but wait for a while before submitting it.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257868/please-revisit-the-captcha-china-issue), on a strike so not closing it myself.