# Please use another captcha than reCaptcha

Tags: feature-request, captcha, recaptcha

ReCaptcha gets worse and worse. Often I need to solve 12 image puzzles before ReCaptcha acknowledges me as a human.

There are a lot of nice CAPTCHA solutions are out there, most self-hosted (which allows for nice data protection as well). Choose any reasonable one except ReCaptcha.

In the  near future, ReCaptcha will lock out many users anyway, see [How to pass ReCaptcha v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546045/how-to-pass-recaptcha-v3)
In an informal survey, people noticed that there are many different browser combinations, which are just untrusted for Google. They seem to get a lot of ReCaptcha v2 image puzzles (what do *you* deem acceptable? I think 12 is way too many) and just fail v3.

So **please use a different CAPTCHA**. Possibly just one with old-style garbled text, which is generated serverside. Hosting your own CAPTCHA isn't too complicated, complies with data retention laws (especially GDPR), and allows setting a reasonable threshold instead of just accepting what Google thinks how many you need to solve today.

Here is the [unofficial reCaptcha v3 compatibility list](https://blog.anghenfil.de/post/28-09-2018.html)

Comment: Very much related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153561/human-verification-page-not-loading-in-china.

Comment: I'm thoroughly sick of identifying buses, hydrants and traffic lights,

Comment: and road signs and company signs...

Comment: Only 12? You're lucky. I do 20+ often.

Comment: @Richard maybe we humans really suck at learning like a machine ....