# Use a different CAPTCHA provider for privacy and security

Tags: feature-request, captcha, privacy, security, recaptcha

*Note: this is not a duplicate of [Replacing reCAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229852/replacing-recaptcha) or [Please use another captcha than reCaptcha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320920/please-use-another-captcha-than-recaptcha), because this post is chiefly about privacy and security concerns, and **not** usability, challenge difficulty, or bots bypassing reCAPTCHA. This is also not a duplicate of [Use a privacy-friendly reCaptcha alternative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333517/use-a-privacy-friendly-recaptcha-alternative), because that post doesn't describe the same vulnerabilities or issues as described here. Perhaps the two could be merged, but they are not duplicates.*

Stack Exchange currently uses Google reCAPTCHA for bot detection. However, this presents several privacy and security concerns, listed later in this post. I think Stack Exchange should switch to using a more private and secure CAPTCHA solution that doesn't track your every click on Stack Exchange. As stated in [Is there anything insecure about Google ReCaptcha?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101326/288551), there are several privacy and security concerns regarding Google reCAPTCHA. One of them I feel is particularly important:

> Tracking: anyone clicking through the reCaptcha 'consents' to be tracked by Google. This may impact your user's privacy, as well as provide a means for Google to track traffic on your website.

Additional vulnerabilities stated in this post include DoS on Google's reCAPTCHA systems preventing authentication and Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks from Google's third-party JavaScript libraries. Unlike the post on Security Stack Exchange, this post is a request for Stack Exchange to migrate to another more secure and private CAPTCHA provider.

Here are some privacy and security concerns regarding Google reCAPTCHA:

- Google tracks users who complete reCAPTCHA.
- Use of reCAPTCHA feeds more data to Google, a huge Internet monopoly that doesn't put privacy first (or second, third, fourth...)
- reCAPTCHA v3 (invisible reCAPTCHA) [tracks your every click and all your activity on the site](https://www.tracefree.com/news/googles-recaptcha-v3-is-a-tracking-pixel/) to prove you're not a robot and classifies you with a "risk level."
- reCAPTCHA v3 (invisible reCAPTCHA) also checks if your browser has a tracking cookie present that tells it if you're logged into a Google account.
- [Cloudflare has stopped using Google reCAPTCHA due to privacy concerns](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/technology/cloudflare-drops-googles-recaptcha-due-to-privacy-concerns/) including targeted advertising based on users' online behavior, which is tracked by almost all Google products, including reCAPTCHA.
- [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101326/288551)s if a Google reCAPTCHA server was ever compromised by attackers or went rogue.
- As previously stated, a [DoS attack on Google's reCAPTCHA servers would prevent authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101326/288551). This is true with any CAPTCHA service, but Google reCAPTCHA is the most commonly used and therefore most likely to be hit by a DoS or DDoS attack.
- The simple fact that Google should not be trusted with any user data due to [data breaches and frequent privacy violations](https://firewalltimes.com/google-data-breach-timeline/).

The alternative? I recommend using hCAPTCHA, which is a [privacy-focused CAPTCHA solution](https://www.hcaptcha.com/) for keeping the bots out, keeping the humans in, and *respecting everyone's privacy and security*. However, any alternative to reCAPTCHA would probably be better privacy- and security-wise. Push back against Google's Internet-wide tracking and support a more privacy-focused alternative on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Proposed duplicates: [Use a privacy-friendly reCaptcha alternative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333517/use-a-privacy-friendly-recaptcha-alternative), [Why can't SE use a non-Google captcha that invades my privacy less?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335309/348196)

Comment: Both of these ask for the same thing: to switch to a different CAPTCHA provider for similar reasons. This would better be served as an answer to that question: "In addition to the privacy reasons pointed out here, there are also these security reasons this switch should be made: [...]". We prefer that requests for the same thing be consolidated into one post so they're easier for staff to handle - that's why the system even allows closing as duplicates of unanswered questions.

Comment: Is Google Captcha the only concern, considering [SE also uses Google Analytics and Google CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331951/241919) heavily?

Comment: @Rob This post *is* actually a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335309/why-cant-se-use-a-non-google-captcha-that-invades-my-privacy-less/362362#362362, thanks for finding that!

Comment: You can ask someone with a dupehammer (or Glo) if they would add that Q&A to the banner's list, if this is reopened you can single-handedly add it yourself (close  / dupe).