# I don't seem to be able to register a Stack Exchange account

Tags: bug, user-accounts, recaptcha

They have started requiring "reputation points" to post in SEM. That's why I post this here, hoping that somebody will move it to the right category for me. I am unable to post there, and the bug makes me unable to post *anywhere* which requires an account:

***The bug report***

For the last several days, it has been impossible to register a Stack Exchange account. After being harassed by reCAPTCHA puzzles for half an hour, finally allowing me through, and after verifying the e-mail address, it just dumps you at this generic error page:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

So, yeah, they literally tell me it's their fault, but somehow, I'm the one affected by it.

I've tried numerous times now over the last few days and this keeps happening. There must be a critical bug causing this, because it's no longer possible to register an account on Stack Exchange. Which means we cannot post any question on Stack Overflow, etc.

Is this being worked on? Is it even known?

---

*** Edit ***

Some other users are having this bug and he referenced that bug. (He posted on ServerFault something for StackOverflow) [source](https://serverfault.com/posts/1014823/revisions)

[image]

Comment: Are you in China by any chance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343197/158100 ?

Comment: There seem to be plenty of new accounts on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen a similar report where a recapthcha was followed by a Server Error but I can't find it here or on MSO. I hope it didn't get roomba-ed.

Comment: ReCAPTCHA is a discriminatory black box...