# Change the source of Google reCAPTCHAs to recaptcha.net so it works in countries where google.com is blocked

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I live in Mainland China, one of some of the few regions in the world with national firewalls. My national firewall blocks the foreign IP addresses of Google, which for the moment provides the CAPTCHA service for the Stack Exchange networks.

Google had enabled their reCAPTCHA service through a dedicated domain: `www.recaptcha.net`, and this had been discussed in [a question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57855838/6230282). This domain resolves to different IP address depending on the origin of the query, and it can responds with an IP address tailored for and is accessible in my country.

I would like to ask SE to adopt such a change, as I've had difficulty verifying myself as a human when posting on the main Stack Overflow site.

**Post-closure update**

This had previously been filed as a bug at [Human verification page not loading in China](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153561/367921)), but in my opinion, it: 1) is dated, and 2) didn't propose a solution.

This post linked a potential solution which had been asked by a Stack Overflow user on the main site; in addition to which this post is tagged very differently from the linked duplicate.

I hope that the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag in that post can be reconsidered based on the proposed solution.

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402339/please-change-the-recaptcha-link-to-ensure-the-site-is-accessible-in-china