# Please change the CAPTCHA so that Chinese can use Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Programmers from china can't visit Wikipedia, but CAPTCHA redirects to a Wikipedia page: That means Stack Overflow refuses Chinese users.

I don't want to comment about the prohibition to Wikipedia in China, but there is a way to fuction CAPTCHA in Stack Overflow within itself, instead of through outside sites.

Comment: This feature request asks about the same thing as this one: [Change the source of Google reCAPTCHAs to recaptcha.net so it works in countries where google.com is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369466/change-the-source-of-google-recaptchas-to-recaptcha-net-so-it-works-in-countries)

Comment: "StackOverflow refuses chinese users" Not actively. Stackoverflow doesn't go out of its way to maybe help Chinese users might be more factual. It's also not clear if this is the only barrier. Some users have messages on their profile pages that the Chinese government might not like for example.

Comment: *"fuction"* is a classic, but replacing it with *"function"* still does not make sense. Do you mean *"to make CAPTCHA function"* (e.g., different word order)? Or something else? (*"fuction"*: For example, at *17 min 07 secs* in [episode 50 of the (original) Stack Overflow podcast, 2009-04-21](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3) (with [Steve Yegge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Yegge)). Amazingly, the MP3 link stills work, whereas the Stack Overflow podcast repository at SoundCloud has been completely wiped out.)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum You peaked my interest but that link doesn't work for me unfortunately. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHWgM.png